# linked list memory diagram

Tags: c, linked-list

```
struct letter
{
char ch;
struct letter *ptr_next;
}
*ptr_first,*ptr_this;
//ptr this contains the address of the first node and ptr this contains the address of last node added.
```

[image]A word chair has to be inserted in the linked list such that C goes into the first node,h in the second and so on..
The attached picture is the memory diagram to fill.
I also added what i tried.Please guide me if i am wrong.[image]
Thanks in advance..

Comment: So what's the problem?  There is enough information in the diagram to solve it, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: SO is not in the business of doing your homework for you or helping you cheat.  Give it a shot first and then ask a question if you run into trouble.  You're not going to learn anything if people do it for you.

Comment: @Feanor:  The question is "Can you do my homework for me?"

Comment: ffof will contain the address of the next node i.e ff11.. ff11 will contain "h" .I need to ask that am i doing it right?

Comment: @fahad, your answer is right.  What's the problem?

Comment: @Goz: Ah, that's it. I wasn't reading between the lines, I see it now. :)

Comment: I wanted to check if my solution was right

Comment: @Fahad:  If you'd written out what you think the answer is and why ... THEN asked if you were right you would have got a HUGELY different response :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer to your question: no.
no, because you left one question mark unresolved at ff15.

Comment: what else? i do not see any other option

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the padding bytes your compiler will insert in your `struct letter`. The addresses of contiguous `struct letter` objects will never end up like in your drawing.

Comment: this a copy from an academicallay (101) homework, "fill in the blanks"

Comment: Unable to get what your saying my friend.

Comment: The Point is: we are not doing/checking your homework for you, but we like to answer questions about your problems.

Comment: @pmg:In this example there will be no padding as the char is of one byte

Comment: @fahad: **precisely** because it is one byte, I'm convinced there will be padding (of course, padding is not mandatory; the compiler is free to do what it pleases)

Comment: ideone ( http://ideone.com/VldYR ) has pointers 4 bytes long and the compiler inserts 3 padding bytes in the structure :)